# How to change Yes/No option in confirmation dialog?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane

I want to change YES and NO to something like Agree/Disagree.
What should I do?

```
int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                          "Are you want to continue the process?",
                                          "YES?",
                                          JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: [as obviously everything is Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button)

Answer (score 31):

You can do the following

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
String[] options = new String[2];
options[0] = "Agree";
options[1] = "Disagree";
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame.getContentPane(), "Message!", "Title", 0, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
```

output is as follows

[image]

For more details about the showOptionDialog() function see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Yes this is working as expected, but is there a way to change font of "Agree" and "Disagree" buttons?. I want to internationalize my application.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `options` parameter to push custom options to [showOptionDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29);

```java
Object[] options = { "Agree", "Disagree" };
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "These are my terms", "Terms",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, 
    options, options[0]);
```

Comment: It work and change for JOptionPane.showOptionDialog but I want to change for JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog

Is it the same way or not?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to checkout [`JOptionPane.showOptionDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object%5b%5d,%20java.lang.Object%29), that will let you push in a text parameter (in array form).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

See [JOptionPane documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html)

```
JOptionPane(Object message, int messageType, int optionType,
        Icon icon, Object[] options, Object initialValue)
```

where options specifies the buttons with initialValue. So you can change them

**Example**

```
Object[] options = { "Agree", "Disagree" };

JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are you want to continue the process?", "information",
JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
null, options, options[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This!!

```
int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you want to continue the process?", "", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        switch (res) {
            case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Process Successfully");
            break;
            case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Process is Canceled");
            break;
        }
```